# TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not list

Tags: python, pygame, typeerror, pygame-surface

I was working on a movement animations since I saw a youtuber explaining how to do it, but I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not list

My code is about 500 lines.

```
# Pygame Template - skeleton for a new pygame project
import pygame
import random
import os
from os import path
vec = pygame.math.Vector2

width = 800
height = 600
FPS = 60
POWERUP_TIME = 5000
title = 'Parkourse'

# Player properties
player_acceleration = 0.5
player_friction = -0.12
player_gravity = 0.8
player_jump = 10

# Starting platforms
platforms_list = [(0,height-40,width,50), # Ground
                  (0,0,800,10),           # Top
                  (0,0,10,600),           # Left Border
                  (790,height-400,10,600),# Right Border
                  (250,height - 160,width-200,10), # Floor 1
                  (0,height - 280,width-200,10),   # Floor 2
                  (250,height - 400,width-100,10)] # Floor 3

# Define Colors
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)

# set up assets folders
game_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
image_folder = os.path.join(game_folder, "Image")
sound_folder = os.path.join(game_folder, "Sound")

# Initialize pygame and create window
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
pygame.display.set_caption(title)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Load all game graphics
background = pygame.image.load(path.join(image_folder, "background.png")).convert()
background_rect = background.get_rect()
no_mvmt_0 = pygame.image.load(path.join(image_folder,"no_mvmt_0.png")).convert()
no_mvmt_1 = pygame.image.load(path.join(image_folder,"no_mvmt_1.png")).convert()
running_0 = pygame.image.load(path.join(image_folder,"running_0.png")).convert()
running_1 = pygame.image.load(path.join(image_folder,"running_1.png")).convert()
jumping_0 = pygame.image.load(path.join(image_folder,"jumping_0.png")).convert()
mini_no_mvmt = pygame.transform.scale(no_mvmt_0, (25,48))
mini_no_mvmt.set_colorkey(white)
scissors = pygame.image.load(path.join(image_folder,"scissors.png")).convert()
mob_left = pygame.image.load(path.join(image_folder,"mob_left.png")).convert()

power_upper_image = {}
power_upper_image['shield_0'] = pygame.image.load(path.join(image_folder,"shield_upper_0.png")).convert()
power_upper_image['shield_1'] = pygame.image.load(path.join(image_folder,"shield_upper_1.png")).convert()
power_upper_image['shield_2'] = pygame.image.load(path.join(image_folder,"shield_upper_2.png")).convert()
power_upper_image['life'] = pygame.image.load(path.join(image_folder,"life_upper.png")).convert()
power_upper_image['power'] = pygame.image.load(path.join(image_folder,"power.png")).convert()



explosion_animation = {}
explosion_animation['normal']=[]
explosion_animation['small']=[]
explosion_animation['player']=[]

for explosion in range(5):
    explose = 'explosion_{}.png'.format(explosion)
    image = pygame.image.load(path.join(image_folder, explose)).convert()
    image.set_colorkey(white)
    image.set_colorkey(black)
    image_normal = pygame.transform.scale(image, (80,80))
    explosion_animation['normal'].append(image_normal)
    image_small = pygame.transform.scale(image, (30, 30))
    explosion_animation['small'].append(image_small)
    death = 'dying_{}.png'.format(explosion)
    image = pygame.image.load(path.join(image_folder, death)).convert()
    image.set_colorkey(white)
    explosion_animation['player'].append(image)

#Load all game sounds
scream_sound = []
for scream in ["slightscream_0.wav", "slightscream_1.wav", "slightscream_2.wav",
                "slightscream_3.wav", "slightscream_4.wav", "slightscream_5.wav",
                "slightscream_6.wav", "slightscream_7.wav", "slightscream_8.wav",
                "slightscream_9.wav", "slightscream_10.wav", "slightscream_11.wav",
                "slightscream_12.wav", "slightscream_13.wav", "slightscream_14.wav"]:
    scream_sound.append(pygame.mixer.Sound(path.join(sound_folder,scream)))

shoot_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(path.join(sound_folder,"shoot.wav"))
shield = pygame.mixer.Sound(path.join(sound_folder,"shield.wav"))
life = pygame.mixer.Sound(path.join(sound_folder,"life.wav"))
special_power = pygame.mixer.Sound(path.join(sound_folder,"special_power.wav"))
death_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(path.join(sound_folder,"death.ogg"))
explosion_sound = []
for sound in ["explosion.wav", "explosion_2.wav"]:
    explosion_sound.append(pygame.mixer.Sound(path.join(sound_folder, sound)))
pygame.mixer.music.load(path.join(sound_folder,"gameplay.ogg"))
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.6)

font_name = pygame.font.match_font('arial')

def draw_text (surf, text,color,size, x, y):
    font = pygame.font.Font(font_name, size)
    text_surface = font.render(text, True, color)
    text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
    text_rect.midtop = (x, y)
    surf.blit(text_surface, text_rect)

def newmob():
    m = Mobs()
    all_sprites.add(m)
    mobs.add(m)

def draw_shield_bar(screen, x,y,percentage):
    if percentage < 0:
        percentage = 0
    bar_lenght = 100
    bar_height = 10
    fill = (percentage / 100) * bar_lenght
    outline_rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,bar_lenght,bar_height)
    fill_rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,fill, bar_height)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, fill_rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, outline_rect, 2) # 2 is the the number of pixels
                                                     # of how wide you want the outline
                                                     # of the rectangle to be

def draw_lives (surface, x, y, lives, image):
    for i in range(lives):
        image_rect = image.get_rect()
        image_rect.x = x + 30 * i
        image_rect.y = y
        surface.blit(image, image_rect)

score = 0

def show_game_over_screen():
    screen.blit(background, background_rect)
    draw_text(screen, "Dang..!",red,100, width/2, 200)
    draw_text(screen, "Score: " + str(score),blue,30, width/2, 330)
    draw_text(screen, "Press any key to retry",blue,30, width/2, 390)
    pygame.display.flip()
    waiting = True
    while waiting:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                waiting = False

def show_start_screen():
    screen.blit(background, background_rect)
    draw_text(screen,"Parkourse!", green, 100, width/2, 200)
    draw_text(screen, "Use the arrow keys to move, S to fire, and space to Jump",blue,30, width/2, 330)
    draw_text(screen, "Press any key to begin",blue,30, width/2, 390)
    pygame.display.flip()
    waiting = True
    while waiting:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                waiting = False

class Player (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # Sprite for the player
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.load_movement_images()
        self.image = self.standing_frame[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.pos = vec(50,500)
        self.vel = vec(0,0)
        self.acc = vec(0,0)
        self.shield = 100
        self.lives = 3
        self.hidden = False
        self.hide_timer = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.power = 1
        self.power_timer = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.running = False
        self.jumping = False
        self.current_frame = 0
        self.last_update = 0

    def load_movement_images(self):
        self.standing_frame = [no_mvmt_0, no_mvmt_1]
        self.running_frame_right = [running_0,running_1]
        self.running_frame_left = []
        for frame in self.standing_frame:
            frame.set_colorkey(white)
        for frame in self.running_frame_right:
            self.running_frame_left.append(pygame.transform.flip(frame,True,False)) # True is horizontaly, False is vertically
            frame.set_colorkey(white)
        self.jumping_frame = jumping_0
        self.jumping_frame.set_colorkey(white)

    def animate(self):
        now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if not self.jumping and not self.running:
            if now - self.last_update > 350:
                self.last_update = now
                self.current_frame = (self.current_frame + 1) % len(self.standing_frame)
                self.image = self.standing_frame

    def jump(self):
        # Jump only if standing on a Platform
        self.rect.x +=1
        hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player,platforms, False)
        self.rect.x -= 1
        if hits:
            self.vel.y = - player_jump

    def update(self):
        self.animate()
        # timeout for powerups
        if self.power >=2 and pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.power_time > POWERUP_TIME:
            self.power -= 1
            self.power_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

        # unhide if hidden
        if self.hidden and pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.hide_timer > 1000:
            self.hidden = False
            self.pos = vec(30, 400)

        self.acc = vec(0,player_gravity)
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT] or keystate[pygame.K_a]:
            self.acc.x = -player_acceleration
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keystate[pygame.K_d]:
            self.acc.x = player_acceleration
        if keystate[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            player.jump()

        # apply friction
        self.acc.x += self.vel.x * player_friction
        # equations of motions
        self.vel += self.acc
        self.pos += self.vel + 0.5 * self.acc
        # wrap around the sides of the screen
        if self.pos.x > 750:
            self.pos.x = 750
        if self.pos.x <= 0:
            self.pos.x = 25

        self.rect.midbottom = self.pos

    def powerup(self):
        self.power += 1
        self.power_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    def shoot(self):
        if self.power == 1:
            bullet = Bullet(self.pos.x + 5, self.pos.y - 20)
            all_sprites.add(bullet)
            bullets.add(bullet)
            shoot_sound.play()
        if self.power >= 2:
            bullet1 = Bullet(self.pos.x + 5, self.pos.y - 20)
            bullet2 = Bullet(self.pos.x + 35, self.pos.y -20)
            all_sprites.add(bullet1)
            all_sprites.add(bullet2)
            bullets.add(bullet1)
            bullets.add(bullet2)
            shoot_sound.play()

    def hide(self):
        # hide the player temporarily
        self.hidden = True
        self.hide_timer = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.pos = vec(0, 6000)

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = scissors
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image.set_colorkey(white)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(scissors, (30,15))
        self.rect.bottom = y
        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.speedx = 10

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        # kill if it moves off the top of the screen
        if self.rect.bottom < 0:
            self.kill()

class Mobs(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = mob_left
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image.set_colorkey(white)
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(0,800)
        self.rect.y = 530
        self.speedx = 2

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x -= self.speedx
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.rect.x = 800

class Explosion(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, center, size, frame):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.size = size
        self.image = explosion_animation[self.size][0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = center
        self.frame = 0
        self.last_update = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.frame_rate = frame

    def update(self):
        now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if now - self.last_update > self.frame_rate:
            self.last_update = now
            self.frame += 1
            if self.frame == len(explosion_animation[self.size]):
                self.kill()
            else:
                center = self.rect.center
                self.image = explosion_animation[self.size][self.frame]
                self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
                self.rect.center = center

class Normal_Power(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, center):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.type = random.choice(['shield_0','shield_1','shield_2'])
        self.image = power_upper_image[self.type]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image.set_colorkey(white)
        self.rect.center = center

class Special_Power(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, center):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.type = random.choice(['life','power'])
        self.image = power_upper_image[self.type]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image.set_colorkey(white)
        self.rect.center = center

class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((w, h))
        self.image.fill(black)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=-1)  # loops = -1 means that pygame will restart the song when it's finished

# Game loop
running = True
new_game = True
game_over = False

while running:
    if new_game:
        show_start_screen()
        new_game = False
        all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
        platforms = pygame.sprite.Group()
        for plat in platforms_list:
            p = Platform (*plat)
            all_sprites.add(p)
            platforms.add(p)
        mobs = pygame.sprite.Group()
        player = Player()
        all_sprites.add(player)
        bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
        powerups = pygame.sprite.Group()
        for i in range(1):
            newmob()
        score = 0
    if game_over:
        show_game_over_screen()
        game_over = False
        all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
        platforms = pygame.sprite.Group()
        for plat in platforms_list:
            p = Platform (*plat)
            all_sprites.add(p)
            platforms.add(p)
        mobs = pygame.sprite.Group()
        player = Player()
        all_sprites.add(player)
        bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
        powerups = pygame.sprite.Group()
        for i in range(1):
            newmob()
        score = 0

    # Keep loop running at the right speed
    clock.tick(FPS)

    # Process input (events)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                player.shoot()

    # Updates
    all_sprites.update()

    # check if player hits a platform - only if falling
    if player.vel.y > 0:
        hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player,platforms,False)
        if hits:
            player.pos.y = hits[0].rect.top
            player.vel.y = 0

    # check to see if a bullet hit a mob
    hits = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(mobs,bullets,True,True)
    for hit in hits:
        score += 1

        random.choice(explosion_sound).play()
        expl = Explosion(hit.rect.center, 'normal', 50)
        all_sprites.add(expl)
        if random.random() > 0.75:
            power = Normal_Power(hit.rect.center)
            all_sprites.add(power)
            powerups.add(power)
        if random.random() > 0.90:
            lives = Special_Power(hit.rect.center)
            all_sprites.add(lives)
            powerups.add(lives)
        newmob()

    # check to see if the mob hit the player
    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, mobs,True)
    for hit in hits:
        random.choice(explosion_sound).play()
        player.shield -= 25
        newmob()
        expl = Explosion(hit.rect.center, 'small', 50)
        all_sprites.add(expl)
        if player.shield <= 0:
            death_sound.play()
            death_animation = Explosion(player.rect.center, 'player', 100)
            all_sprites.add(death_animation)
            player.hide()
            player.lives -= 1
            player.shield = 100
        else:
            random.choice(scream_sound).play()

    # check if the player hit a powerup
    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, powerups, True)
    for hit in hits:
        if hit.type == 'shield_0':
            player.shield += 5
            if player.shield >= 100:
                player.shield = 100
            shield.play()
        if hit.type == 'shield_1':
            player.shield += 20
            if player.shield >= 100:
                player.shield = 100
            shield.play()
        if hit.type == 'shield_2':
            player.shield += 20
            if player.shield >= 100:
                player.shield = 100
            shield.play()
        if hit.type == 'life':
            player.lives += 1
            if player.lives >= 3:
                player.lives = 3
            life.play()
        if hit.type == 'power':
            special_power.play()
            player.powerup()

    # if the player died and the explosion finished playing
    if player.lives == 0 and not death_animation.alive():
        game_over = True

    # Draw / Render
    screen.fill(white)
    screen.blit(background, background_rect)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    draw_text(screen,str(score),red,30, width/ 2, 30)
    draw_text(screen,"Score:",red,30, width / 2, 3)
    draw_shield_bar(screen,90,20, player.shield)
    draw_lives(screen,95,40,player.lives, mini_no_mvmt)

    # *after* drawing everything, flip the display
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: That's way too much code. Provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and either upload the images or just replace them by `pygame.Surface`s. Also, post the full traceback.

Comment: Hi skrx, I barely know where my problem is, but when I run the program, it says: 
" line 475, in draw
    self.spritedict[spr] = surface_blit(spr.image, spr.rect)
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not list "

Comment: That's not enough information. Please add the full error message that you get to your question. I can only see that you're using a list in a place where a pygame.Surface is required.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\.....\parkour.py", line 524, in <module>
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 475, in draw
    self.spritedict[spr] = surface_blit(spr.image, spr.rect)
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not list
libpng warning: bKGD: invalid
[Finished in 2.277s]

Comment: This is what I get sir, if you need more informations, let me know

Comment: You're passing a list where a pygame.Surface is expected. We cannot look over 500 lines of code to find your problem. You need to narrow it down (a [mcve]). The quality of this code suggest that you should be comfortable with python and should know basic debugging and thus be able to narrow down the code. If you've followed a tutorial then just show us what lines you added for the error to occur.

Comment: Heh, I've just figured it out. :P But I've had to replace all of the images first and remove the sounds which was not nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by a sprite in your `all_sprites` group that has a list as its `self.image` attribute. I've just printed the sprites before the `all_sprites.draw(screen)` line

```
for sprite in all_sprites:
    print(sprite, sprite.image)
```

and it was the player sprite which had a list as its image.

```
<Player sprite(in 1 groups)> [<Surface(40x25x32 SW)>, <Surface(40x25x32 SW)>]
```

In the `load_movement_images` method you define `self.standing_frame` as a list of two images/pygame.Surfaces and in `__init__` you set `self.image` to the first item of that list. But in the `animate` method you set self.image to the whole list instead of the active image `self.image = self.standing_frame` and that leads to the error.

```
class Player (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # Sprite for the player
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.load_movement_images()
        # self.image is the first image in the
        # self.standing_frame list.
        self.image = self.standing_frame[0]
        # ...

    def load_movement_images(self):
        self.standing_frame = [no_mvmt_0, no_mvmt_1]
        # ...

    def animate(self):
        now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if not self.jumping and not self.running:
            if now - self.last_update > 350:
                self.last_update = now
                self.current_frame = (self.current_frame + 1) % len(self.standing_frame)
                # Here you set the self.image to the self.standing_fram list instead one image.
                self.image = self.standing_frame
                # It should be:
                # self.image = self.standing_frame[self.current_frame]
```

Comment: Ahhh it's confusing me so much.. I still don't get it. Do you mind detailing a little bit more?

Comment: Mmmmm never mind I just got it!
self.image = self.standing_frame [self.current_frame]